# Looping each character of a string variable when writing to csv file. How to avoid this?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, printing

**Problem Statement:**
Trying to Print variable value which is string type into CSV file as each line for one row

**What I tried:**

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv

df = pd.read_table('c:\csv\input1.csv', engine='python', sep="\s*,\s*", skipinitialspace=True, usecols=[0, 1], header='infer')
count=0
print(','.join(df.columns))
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    headers = {
        'X-Requested-By': 'cli',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    params = (
        ('query', row["Private Ip"]),
        ('range', '86400'),
        ('limit', '100'),
        ('sort', 'timestamp:desc'),
        ('pretty', 'true'),
    )
    
    response = requests.get('http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:9000/api/search/universal/relative', headers=headers, params=params,
                            auth=('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx'))
   
    text = response.text
    pretty_json = json.loads(text)
    if pretty_json.get('messages'):
        output = (row['Account Name'] + ',' + row['Private Ip'] + ',' +'Yes')
        with open('c:\csv\pdftable.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for i in output:
                writer.writerow([i])
        print(row['Account Name'] + ',' + row['Private Ip'] + ',' +'Yes')
    else:
        print(row['Account Name'] + ',' + row['Private Ip']+ ',' + 'No')
    count+=1
```

**Inputs:
My CSV:**

```
Account Name,Hosts 
ABCD,XX.XXX.XX.XX           
ABCDE,XX.XX.XXX.XX
ABCDEF,XX.XX.XXX.XXX
ABCDEFG,XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

**Output When I put it to console:** (it's fine when I print it in terminal)

```
Account Name,Hosts 
ABCD,XX.XXX.XX.XX,Yes           
ABCDE,XX.XX.XXX.XX,Yes
ABCDEF,XX.XX.XXX.XXX,Yes
ABCDEFG,XX.XXX.XX.XX,Yes
```

**Problem when Output to CSV:**

The expected output in CSV

```
Account Name,Hosts 
ABCD,XX.XXX.XX.XX,Yes           
ABCDE,XX.XX.XXX.XX,Yes
ABCDEF,XX.XX.XXX.XXX,Yes
ABCDEFG,XX.XXX.XX.XX,Yes
```

**Real output coming into CSV:**

```
A

B

C

D

-

X
.
X
.
x
.
X
```

I read through some articles, where python treats a string as a sequence, which will iterate all character, I guess that is what happens, I tried some other suggestion, to put writer.row([data]] as a list, but still output in CSV is coming like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you iterate over the desired `row` and use `writer.writerow()` on each character.

What you need to do instead is:

```
with open('c:\csv\pdftable.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(output)
```

So it will export the entire output to 1 row each time.

## Edit

Try the following:

```
import csv
output = "ABCD,XX.XXX.XX.XX,Yes"

with open('test.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([output])
```

This output inside the "test.csv":

```
"ABCD,XX.XXX.XX.XX,Yes"
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working, now I find only one row in csv like below A,B,C,D,x,x,.,x,x,x,.,x,.,x,x,x,",",Y,e,s and also this is 4th row of output and its ignoring all other rows even in above format.

Comment: @asp see my edit to the question, is it what you are looking for?

Comment: yeah, now it prints as expected, but one small glitch i found, though console output printing all rows, but in csv , only 3rd row its writing, not all, any clue u get from my code ?

Comment: @asp probably the `if-else` causing it, but you need to debug properly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for i in output:
    writer.writerow([i])
```

you want to use:

```
writer.writerow(output)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but its not working, now I find only one row in csv like below A,B,C,D,x,x,.,x,x,x,.,x,.,x,x,x,",",Y,e,s and also this is 4th row of output and its ignoring all other rows even in above format

Comment: @asp you have to stop opening/closing .csv file every time you write a line, move `with open(...)` out of the loop.